# Geometry Problem about Circles and Tangents

Tags: geometry, circles

It is the second problem from my maths notebooks, which is still unsolved. I translated it from Russian, so their may be some discrepancies in translation. So, I also added image.
First problem was [Geometry Problem about Cyclic Quadrilateral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176663/geometry-problem-about-cyclic-quadrilateral).

> The circle $S_1$ with centre $C_1 (a_1 , b_1)$ and radius $r_1$ touches (or tangent to) externally the circle $S_2$ with centre $C_2 (a_2 , b_2)$ and radius $r_2$. Their common tangent passes through the origin.
>
> Show that, $(a_1)^2 - (a_2)^2 + (b_1)^2 - (b_2)^2 = (r_1)^2 - (r_2)^2 \; \; \; $  (i)
>
> If, also other tangents from origin are perpendicular, prove that $|a_2b_1 -a_1b_2| = |a_1a_2 + b_1b_2| \; \; \; $  (ii)

[image: Here is image, if translation is not clear enough.]

I have solved (i), so I need solution only for (ii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that angle $C_1OC_2 = \frac {\pi} 4$

So the angle between x-axis and $ OC_1$ is $\frac \pi 4$ more or less than angle between x-axis and $OC_2$

Hint: Use compound angle formulae and $\frac {b_1}{a_1}$ and $\frac {b_2}{a_2}$.

Comment: How to use that fact???

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the hint given by $tomi, we have:-

$\frac {b_1}{a_1}$ is the slope of $OC_1$; and similarly, $\frac {b_2}{a_2}$ is the slope of $OC_2$.

Finding the angle between 2 lines (passing through the origin) with slopes known is given by a standard formula. It can be found in like:-

http://www.vitutor.com/geometry/line/angle_lines.html